# Angular Cli Req Node version ^14.15

Tags: angular-cli, angular12

I have global cli v 12.1 and local version 12.1

5th row from end told that i need version >=14.0.0

But When i try to ***ng serve*** or ***ng v*** i got:

```
Node.js version v14.3.0 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v12.14 or v14.15.

Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.
```

@angular/cli package.json (from node modules, package-lock told same):

```
{
  "name": "@angular/cli",
  "version": "12.1.0",
  "description": "CLI tool for Angular",
  "main": "lib/cli/index.js",
  "bin": {
    "ng": "./bin/ng"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "angular",
    "Angular CLI",
    "devkit",
    "sdk",
    "Angular DevKit",
    "angular-cli"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node ./bin/postinstall/script.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular-cli.git"
  },
  "author": "Angular Authors",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/angular/angular-cli",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "0.1201.0",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "12.1.0",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "12.1.0",
    "@schematics/angular": "12.1.0",
    "@yarnpkg/lockfile": "1.1.0",
    "ansi-colors": "4.1.1",
    "debug": "4.3.1",
    "ini": "2.0.0",
    "inquirer": "8.1.1",
    "jsonc-parser": "3.0.0",
    "npm-package-arg": "8.1.5",
    "npm-pick-manifest": "6.1.1",
    "open": "8.2.1",
    "ora": "5.4.1",
    "pacote": "11.3.4",
    "resolve": "1.20.0",
    "semver": "7.3.5",
    "symbol-observable": "4.0.0",
    "uuid": "8.3.2"
  },
  "ng-update": {
    "migrations": "@schematics/angular/migrations/migration-collection.json",
    "packageGroup": {
      "@angular/cli": "12.1.0",
      "@angular-devkit/architect": "0.1201.0",
      "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "12.1.0",
      "@angular-devkit/build-webpack": "0.1201.0",
      "@angular-devkit/core": "12.1.0",
      "@angular-devkit/schematics": "12.1.0"
    }
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0",
    "npm": "^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6",
    "yarn": ">= 1.13.0"
  }
}
```